# FInd the number of pairs $(A,B)$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $n,r,s$ be given, where $n\geq 1$,$1\leq r\leq n$ and $1\leq s \leq n$.
>
> a) determine the number of pairs $(A,B)$ with $A\subseteq N_n, |A|=r,B\subseteq N_n, \text{and} |B|=s $

Now my intuition says that these two *could* intersect. But dont have to. So I would define it as being
$$
A \cup B = 2 \leq r+s\leq 2n 
$$

But My intuition seems to bee too easy. any pointers?

Comment: By $N_n$, do you mean the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$?

Comment: yes for example $N_9 = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ (had to fulfull minimum requirements for comment :))

Comment: @WiseStrawberry In combinatorics, a common way to denote the set containing the first $n$ integers is $[n]$. For example, your $N_9$ would be $[9]$.

Comment: Our lectures always denote this as $N_9$, I will keep this in mind for future questions.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways of denoting the set $\{1,2,...n\}$. For example, I'm used to seeing $\langle N \rangle$ or $[N]$. Definitely worth saying what you mean in the question, however you abbreviate it.

Comment: will do, helps me not to forget the actual meaning of what I am saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you're making things more difficult for yourself by considering the union of $A$ and $B$ rather than considering the sets separately, since each of the sets are chosen independently.

The question can be broken down as follows:

1. how many valid choices are there for $A$
2. how many valid choices are there for $B$
3. how many pairs of $A$ and $B$ are there

For 1, we just need the number of distinct subsets of $N_n$ that are of size $r$.  You can compute this as
$$
\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}
$$
2 amounts to the same except with $s$ instead of $r$
$$
\binom{n}{s}=\frac{n!}{s!(n-s)!}
$$
Finally, since we made these choices independently, the total number of pairs is just the product of these two numbers.  So, our final answer is
$$
\text{Total}=\binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{s}=\frac{(n!)^2}{r!s!(n-r)!(n-s)!}
$$

Comment: so $$
total = \binom{n}{r} \binom{n}{s}$$
? Thank you :)

Comment: @WiseStrawberry Exactly! It's very easy to over-think these problems (:

Comment: seems so easy! :)

Comment: Well, it's only part a)...

Comment: true. If I have any questions on b) should I edit my post, or ask a new question?

Comment: Ask a new question for best results.