# show that $|\cup^n_{i=0} X_i| = \sum \binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{r-i}\binom{n-r}{s-i}$

Tags: combinatorics

> Define $$
> X_i = \{(D,E,F) : D \subseteq N_n, |D| = r,E\subseteq D, |E|=r-i,F\subseteq N_n - D, |F|=s-i\}
> $$
>   Where $N_n$ denotes the set of all subsets.
>
> $$|X_0 \cup X_1 \cup \ldots\cup X_n| = \sum_{i=0}^n  \binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{r-i}\binom{n-r}{s-i}$$

Now my first intuition was to draw a venn-diagram to visualize the problem. This helped a lot and makes it clear to me that this is true. At first I noticed that all $X_i$ are independent and as such the LHS can be written as:
$$
\begin{align}
|X_0 \cup X_1 \cup \ldots\cup X_n| &=\sum_{i=0}^n|X_i|\\
&= \dots
\end{align}
$$
Now the only thing I can think of is: its true, so just write it out. Because the first Binom is calling D, the second one E and the last one F and adding all of them together. It seems really obvious. But actually writing it out is the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes exactly like the accepted answer for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416738/find-the-number-of-pairs-a-b).

For $X_i$, there are $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ choices for $D$, $\binom{r}{r-i}=\frac{r!}{(r-i)!(r-(r-i))!}$ choices for $E$ and $\binom{n-r}{s-i}=\frac{(n-r)!}{(s-i)!(n-r-(s-i))!}$ choices for $F$. Hence $|X_i|=\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{r-i}\binom{n-r}{s-i}$ and $$|X_0 \cup X_1 \cup \ldots\cup X_n| =\sum_{i=0}^n|X_i|=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{r-i}\binom{n-r}{s-i}$$

Comment: but its almost like we're restating the question. is my step of saying that they are independent even necessary?

Comment: Independence of $X_i$ implies $|X_0 \cup X_1 \cup \ldots\cup X_n| =\sum_{i=0}^n|X_i|$.

Comment: ok thanks, so it was necessary.

Comment: Through Venn it is obvious.